# Call boolean instance method as a 'scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model

```
Email
```

and an instance method

```
def sent_to_user?(user)
  self.who_to == user
end
```

where who_to is another instance method doing some complicated stuff to check.

There's a lot more stuff going on in the background there so I can't easily turn it into an activerecord query.

I want to do something like:

```
scope :sent_to_user, -> (user) { sent_to_user?(user)} 

@user.emails.sent_to_user
```

and return a only those emails that return true for 'sent_to_user?'

Have tried

```
scope :sent_to_user, -> (user) { if sent_to_user?(user)}
```

....etc.

Not quite sure how to build that scope / class method

Comment: Shouldn't that be `to_whom`?

Comment: OK. That made me laugh... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (at least shouldn't) use scopes this way. Scopes are for returning ActiveRecord relations onto which *additional* scopes can be chained. If you want to use a scope, you should produce the necessary SQL to perform the filtering in the database.

If you want to filter results in Ruby and return an array, you should use a class-level method, *not* a scope:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sent_to_user(user)
    select { |record| record.sent_to_user?(user) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I gathered that. I'd tried a couple of variations with class methods already. Guess the main point is that if I'm chaining this it needs to go on the end of a chain of scopes.

Comment: @Carpela Yes, *or* you can reproduce whatever logic is involved in performing the filtering in the database, which is often the better option.

Comment: Not easy in this case as I'm using the Mail gem to parse different types of email addresses from text. Not sure Postgres has a plugin for that...

Answer (score 0):

You should write who_to in ActiveRecord logic, like

> scope :sent_to_user, -> (user) { joins(:recipient)where(recipient_id: user.id)}

Comment: who_to is not an association. It's a bit more complicated than that. (due to other restrictions in the application)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user `has_many :emails` you can do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails

  # ...

  def emails_sent_to_user
    emails.select { |e| e.sent_to_user?(self) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I worked out a method to do the checking which is a bit of a hack but works in this case, might be useful to somebody. 
The issue with the accepted solution, though it's certainly the only way to do it based on the restrictions I described, is that performance can be seriously sluggish.

I'm now using:

```
scope :sent_to_user, -> (user) {"json_email -> 'to' ILIKE ?", "%#{user.email)}%"}
```

Where "json_email" is an email object parsed into json (it's the way we store them in the db). This cut out the need to use the Mail gem and increased performance dramatically.